# NDMP NAS for HP EVA4400 SAN

Tags: storage-area-network, hp, emc, ndmp

We use EMC Celerra filer for our EMC array and it supports NDMP.n remote site we have EVA4400 HP SAN and it seems that our only option for NAS is Windows Storage Option.
What if we want to use NDMP?Surely HP should have something that match Celerra?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Given NDMP was developed by NetApps and Legato, both HP competitors, and is far from a standard and is meant for NAS boxes rather then FC boxes there's no reason whatsoever for HP to support NDMP. That said HP's 'Data Protector' backup software DOES work with both NetApp AND HP EVA boxes, take a look to see if it meets your needs.

Comment: thank you chopper,

 I will have a look.
BTW, EMC is a competetor of NetApp however they did manage to get NDMP working on Celerra.

Answer (score 1):

Data Protector supports NDMP.  I'ver never used it, but I see it in the options for types of backups you can create.

Comment: isn't that kind of, sort of, what I said?